# Cutting a clip from iPod library file

Tags: ipod, clipping, recording

My requirements are as follows:

I need to access a song from iPod library and play it(which is doable). I have implemented this using Assets library, and now I need to trim that song programmatically, so that I can get a clip of it. One application is already on the app store featuring same functionality, called "Ringtone Designer" Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are retrieving the ALAsset of the song (since you say that you already know how to play it start-to-stop).

Now, to select parts of it you want to extract you can call the Method defaultRepresentation on the ALAsset, then call getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: on that ALAssetRepresentation-Object.

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ALAssetRepresentation

If the song is encoded you might have to decode it first.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply eznme and I have been able to resolve the above issue but now the problem is that it's working for WAV format but not MP3.

Comment: Hi, that's what i feared. The Asset-Library does not transparently decode the compressed data (which would be nice). ALAssetPropertyRepresentations is an NSArray of possible representations you can get from the ALAsset (mp3), one these strings should be wav,wave,raw or similar; you can then use that string (the "UTI") to call the method representationForUTI: instead of defaultRepresentation.